# Is there a way i can find Products of ids i have mapped

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have an orders model. My orders arrays has products and their ID's . I have mapped in the products in the Orders model and managed to get their ID's and saved them as a constant.

Then i wanted to find the products in the Products schema using the id's i have saved however am having this error

**Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'Topology'\n    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'\n    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'\n    --- property 'topology' closes the circle",**

Below is my code. I don't know where i am going wrong.

```
const sellerProductsOrdered = asyncHandler (async (req, res) => {
    const Orders = await Order.find();
    const ordersList =  Orders.map(order => {
        return order;
    });

    const ordersListProductsIds = ordersList.map(product => {
        return product.id;
    });

    console.log(ordersListProductsIds);

    const productsfoundusingIds = await ordersListProductsIds.forEach(() => {
        const results = Product.find({_id: ordersListProductsIds});
        res.json(results);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the Orders schema? And what do you expect this to do? `const ordersList =  Orders.map(order => { return order; });` Because it doesn't do anything. Also instead of getting all the data from db you can actually select just what you need. I mean if you only want Order's product then use : `Order.find().select('product')` or even `select('product.id')` and to find Products by Id you need to use `$in` operator: `Product.find({ _id: { $in: ordersListProductsIds }})` assuming the `ordersListProductsIds` is an array of ids.

Comment: Can you explain what you want the function to return? The problem may be that you are trying to find the `Product`s using the `Order`s IDs. You should post the `Order` schema definition (as Molda suggested)